# How to fix GUI components "leaving" their panels or taking up more space they they are supposed to?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I am trying to make a GUI for a game. I am very new to Java, especially GUI. The code below is a snippet which is supposed to make a `JFrame` with nested panels for organization. It works until I add buttons to the button panel. They end up on the `boardBckg` panel. If I manage to place them on the correct panel the `JTextField` disappears or it takes up the entire screen. I have been working on this part of the code for the past two days and I could really use GUI tips.

```
private void makeWindow()
    {

    boardPanel = new JPanel();
    boardBckg = new JPanel();
    menuPanel = new JPanel();
    save = new JButton("Save");
    save.setSize(Buttons);
    load = new JButton("Load");
    load.setSize(Buttons);
    replay = new JButton ("Replay");
    replay.setSize(Buttons);
    words = new JTextField();

    frame = new JFrame(title);

    boardPanel.setSize(PANEL);
    boardPanel.setMaximumSize(MAX);
    boardPanel.setMinimumSize(MIN);
    boardPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(m,n));
    boardBckg.setSize(1000, 1000);
    boardBckg.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    boardBckg.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BoxLayout vertical = new BoxLayout(menuPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    menuPanel.setSize(500, 1000);
    menuPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    menuPanel.setLayout(vertical);
    frame.add(boardBckg);
    frame.add(menuPanel);
    JPanel iGiveUp = new JPanel();
    iGiveUp.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    buttons.add(save);
    buttons.add(load);
    buttons.add(replay);

    menuPanel.add(iGiveUp);

    menuPanel.add(buttons);
    iGiveUp.add(words);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) Remove any code that includes `setSize(..`. Don't try to guess the size a panel needs (unless it is a custom painted panel, in which case it should return a valid **preferred** size). A frame is best sized by `pack()`.

Comment: Sorry, new at posting here. I wasn't sure which part of my code is the actual problem. Pack () has resulted in my frames being nonexistent for the most part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boardBckg.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The default layout of a JPanel is the FlowLayout. You can't just specify a BorderLayout constraint when you add the component to the panel.

```
frame.add(boardBckg);
frame.add(menuPanel);
```

The default layout for (the content pane of) the frame is a BorderLayout. If you don't specify a constraint, then the component is added to the BorderLayout.CENTER. Problem is only one component can be added to the CENTER so you only see the last comoponent added.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Component should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is packed and made visible. So the above statement should be the last statement in your constructor.

I have no ideas what your desired layout is but you need to start with something simple and take advantage of the default BorderLayout of the frame.

So your basic logic might be something like:

```
JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel()
menuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
menuPanel.add(...);
menuPanel.add(...);

JPanel center = new JPanel();
center.setLayout(...);
center.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
center.add(...);

frame.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

The main point is to break the panels down logically and add them to the frame one at a time. So first get the menu and its child components added to the frame is the correct position. Then you can add the CENTER panel and its child components.